# Where to put Java Resource Bundle in Project Environment

Tags: java, resourcebundle

I am trying to use resource bundle in my project. i am new for development. is it professional way to put property files inside `src/` folder i mean inside jar.

Also i have tried by placing my propert `[AppProp]` outside of the `src` folder `[/resources/properties/AppProp]`. I have added **Add Class Folder** from build path eclipse. I am trying to run this in eclipse. But it says Can't find bundle for base name. Please see my below code. Please provide any suggestion.

```
public class PropertyReader {

    private String bundleName = null;

    ResourceBundle resourceBundle = null;

    public PropertyReader(String bundle){
        this.bundleName = bundle;
        loadProperty();
    }

    public void loadProperty(){
        try{
            resourceBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(bundleName);
        } catch(Exception e){
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String a[]){
        try{
            PropertyReader pr = new PropertyReader("resources/properties/AppProp");
        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to describe in more detail how you're building your project. Generally, best practice is to use Maven or Gradle and the Standard Directory Layout.

Comment: Try `ResourceBundle.getBundle("resources/properties/AppProp")`

Comment: Arvind, I am placing outside of /src folder ie. /resources/properties/AppProp.properties. so it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to change the code. But make sure following

1) You are providing the correct file path.

2) File type must be `.properties` in your case it should be  be like `AppProp.properties`

There are lot of techniques/standards to organize your source files and code.

But for now above points are the solution of your problem.

Comment: Thanks, is it professional way to put property files inside src/ folder i mean inside jar.

Comment: As i said, there are lot of techniques to organize the src files but most of the api following the standard of putting resource bundle under the src folder of the java project.